# Como ejecutar angular en localhost con https y certificado ssl?

Tags: angular, localhost, geolocation-api

estoy utilizando la herramienta geolocation de javascript, sin embargo cuando ejecuto mi programa desde un navegador web en dispositivos moviles no me permite utilizar geolocation por no estar en una red segura ya que mi proyecto angular se ejecuta de forma convencional en http, existe alguna forma de emular una conexion segura aun estando en un ambiente de desarrollo?

Comment: que ha intentado? porque obviamente la respuesta es sí

Comment: `ng serve --ssl`, Revisa: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39210467/get-angular-cli-to-ng-serve-over-https